# Unity: Отсутствуют некоторые Header-и в Inspector-е

Tags: unity3d, header

Всем привет!

У меня в скрипте вот такой код -

```
[Header("PictureInformation")]
int pixelsCountX, pixelsCountY, paperType;
float pixelLength, containerWidth, containerHeight;
public float padding;
public Text CursorCoordinates, PictureSize, DocumentSize, Name;
public GameObject ToolsPanel;
public GameObject[] ButtonsGroup;
public ToggleGroup Tools;

[Header("Canvas")]
Texture2D Picture, Background;
public RawImage LayerRawImage, BackgroundRawImage;
public GameObject Canvas, Container;

[Header("Information")]
public string toolTag;
public bool onCanvas;
public Vector2 MousePosition, OnPixel;
public Vector2Int OnPixelInt;
```

Но в инспекторе [такой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH4dU.png) вид -

[image]

То есть отсутствуют Header-и "PictureInformation" и "Canvas".
**Как мне это исправить?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом нет ничего странного, как и в решении вашей проблемы, которое вы нашли.

Во-первых: [[Header("")]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HeaderAttribute.html) - это атрибут поля. Т.е. какой-то дополнительный модификатор/метка, который применяется к конкретному полю. [Подробнее об атрибутах можно узнать в документации C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/).

Во-вторых: редактор в Unity рисуется с помощью специальных классов (PropertyDrawer), которые создаются для всех публичных или помеченных атрибутом [SerializeField] полей.

Теперь вернёмся к самому Header - это класс наследник [DecoratorDrawer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DecoratorDrawer.html). Т.е. он не мешает своему `PropertyDrawer` рисовать поле, а просто определённым образом его дополняет.

Теперь к итогу) вы добавили атрибут к приватному полю, которое не рисуется в инспекторе, а соответственно для него не создаётся `PropertyDrawer`, а раз нет его, то и Header никак не влияет на картину, которую вы видите в редакторе.

```
[Header("PictureInformation")]
public float padding;
public Text CursorCoordinates, PictureSize, DocumentSize, Name;
public GameObject ToolsPanel;
public GameObject[] ButtonsGroup;
public ToggleGroup Tools;
int pixelsCountX, pixelsCountY, paperType;
float pixelLength, containerWidth, containerHeight;

[Header("Canvas")]
public RawImage LayerRawImage, BackgroundRawImage;
public GameObject Canvas, Container;
Texture2D Picture, Background;

[Header("Information")]
public string toolTag;
public bool onCanvas;
public Vector2 MousePosition, OnPixel;
public Vector2Int OnPixelInt;
```

Comment: То есть что мне писать чтобы всё было правильно? Можно пример?

Comment: @AltF4, располагайте ваш Header над первым полем вашей группы, которое будет рисоваться в редакторе. В ответ добавил ваш код с реализацией, которая будет выглядеть так - как вы того хотите. В ответе я просто постарался объяснить вам в чем же причина вашей "ошибки" и почему всё на самом деле логично)

Answer (score 1):

Способ решения очень странный но всё таки это решает проблему.
Надо чтобы после Header-а была именно одна public переменная.
Тут например такое решение -

```
[Header("PictureInformation")]
public ToggleGroup Tools;
int pixelsCountX, pixelsCountY, paperType;
float pixelLength, containerWidth, containerHeight;
public float padding;
public Text CursorCoordinates, PictureSize, DocumentSize, Name;
public GameObject ToolsPanel;
public GameObject[] ButtonsGroup;

[Header("Canvas")]
public GameObject Canvas;
Texture2D Picture, Background;
public RawImage LayerRawImage, BackgroundRawImage;
public GameObject Container;

[Header("Information")]
public string toolTag;
public bool onCanvas;
public Vector2 MousePosition, OnPixel;
public Vector2Int OnPixelInt;
```